# Linkedin fetch wrong data when sharing link (only canonical url data)

Tags: html, linkedin-api, share, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm having issues with sharing a website on Linkedin

I have a https://www.exemple.com website which is correctly crawled by Linkedin

And I added a page https://www.exemple.com/page
Linkedin's preview for this page is the same as the canonical https://www.exemple.com
Even though the meta datas for the 2 pages are not the same

I know the meta data are correct because it works perfectly on other social networks (Slack, Discord, Facebook etc...)

As I can see on https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector, Linkedin considers that it has scrapped my page

[post inspector screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Movt.png)

It is surely caused by LinkedIn, but I think the link sharing is working on other websites or blog. So maybe I can find a solution

Comment: If anyone here works at linkedin: I'll pay you to fix this!
I have the exact same problem, contacted linkedin support several times, but they don't care at all, and just ask me if they can log in with my account to try and reproduce the issue, even though i explicitly told them several times it has absolutely nothing to do with the account... No chance. :(

Answer (score 1):

in my case i changed `content` of the `name="og:url"` meta tag. and it starts to show right image for that page

```html
<meta name="og:url" content="https://www.exemple.com/page"  />
```